# Java Cucumber: Specify target tags in the definition steps

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

Is it possible to specify a (or several) target tags in the definition steps?

For instance, I have two features:

```
feature1.feature
@feature1
...
And I click on "save" button
...

feature2.feature
@feature2
...
And I click on "save" button
...
```

Both features are using the same glue files (they have a lot of common steps).

And I need that these steps have a different implementation for the rule:

```
@And("^I click on \"([^\"]*)\" link$")
```

How can i do this? Is there any annotation to specify that a definition step is used only for a (or several) tags? I would to do something like this:

```
@And("^I click on \"([^\"]*)\" link$")
@Something("@feature1")
public void i_click_on_link_feature1(String option) {
    ...
}

@And("^I click on \"([^\"]*)\" link$")
@Something("@feature2")
public void i_click_on_link_feature2(String option) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to differentiate step definitions based on feature file tags. Suggest you change the wording of the steps where you want different step definition method.
Only the Before and After hooks take feature file tags which in your case will not serve any purpose

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can get the tag information in scenario.getSourceTagNames(), the full source code is: @Before  public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) { scenario.getSourceTagNames(); }